# Error al intentar comparar fechas de dos series temporales: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Estoy realizando una transformación de datos y necesito correr un `while` entre periodos de fechas, pero tengo el error:

> "TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'"

He visto con `type()` que tipo de dato son y ambos son `class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'` por lo tanto no entiendo que pasa.

Les adjunto mi código completo para que lo vean y un archivo CSV para que lo ejecuten y realicen la prueba:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import time

fecha_i=[]
fecha_f=[]
contador=[]
id=[]
contador={}
contador = defaultdict(list)

df = pd.read_csv('contour-export-2017-12-14.csv', header=0, sep=',',parse_dates = ['FCH_HORA_INICIO'],dayfirst = True, usecols=[0,3,6,7])

fecha_i=df['FCH_HORA_INICIO']
fecha_f=df['FCH_HORA_TERMINO']
id=df['ID']

acumulado=fecha_i[0]
i=1
k=0

print(type(acumulado))
print(type(fecha_i[0]))

while(acumulado<datetime.now()):
    acumulado=fecha_i[0]+timedelta(days=i)
    k=0
    while k<=len(df)-1:
        if acumulado>=fecha_i[k] and acumulado<=fecha_f[k]:
            contador[acumulado].append(str(ID[k]))
            k=k+1
        else:
            k=k+1
    i=i+1
```

Archivo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18sKmsg9MSs_t1JWKRYArxsVP4OPud4jL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Te recomiendo hacer tu procesamiento al estilo de pandas, es decir de forma vectorial o al menos usando las funciones que provee la libreria. :P

Comment: @eyllanesc mi idea es agrupar los registros por día, pero cada registro tiene un inicio y fin, por eso utilizo el while para contar todos los que hay por día. Sabes si podría hacerlo más rápido por un group by o algo así? o da para tirarlo en otra pregunta?

Comment: Puedes obtener los sub-dataframes a traves de un filtro, mira el siguiente ejemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22898920/6622587

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al convertir los datos a tiempo a traves de parse_dates lo convierte a `Timestamp`, este tipo de datos no sirven para hacer comparaciones, lo que debes hacer es convertirlo a datetime a traves de la función to_datetime():

```
fecha_i= pd.to_datetime(df['FCH_HORA_INICIO'], errors='coerce')
fecha_f= pd.to_datetime(df['FCH_HORA_TERMINO'], errors='coerce')
```

Code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import time

fecha_i=[]
fecha_f=[]
contador=[]
id=[]
contador={}
contador = defaultdict(list)

df = pd.read_csv('contour-export-2017-12-14.csv', 
    header=0, sep=',',
    parse_dates = ['FCH_HORA_INICIO'],
    dayfirst = True, usecols=[0,3,6,7])

fecha_i= pd.to_datetime(df['FCH_HORA_INICIO'], errors='coerce')
fecha_f= pd.to_datetime(df['FCH_HORA_TERMINO'], errors='coerce')

ID=df['ID']

acumulado= fecha_i[0]
i=1
k=0

while acumulado < datetime.now():
    acumulado=fecha_i[0]+timedelta(days=i)
    k=0
    while k<= len(df)-1:
        if acumulado>=fecha_i[k] and acumulado<=fecha_f[k]:
            contador[acumulado].append(str(ID[k]))
            k=k+1
        else:
            k=k+1
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no estas parseando la columna `'FCH_HORA_TERMINO'` porque no se lo indicas en el argumento `parse_dates` por lo que el tipo de dato que contiene la columna `FCH_HORA_TERMINO` son cadenas Python, mientras que `FCH_HORA_INICIO` es una columna de tipo `datetime64` (NumPy).

Basta con que indiques a `parse_dates` que tenga también esta columna en cuenta como fecha y la parsee a `datetime64[ns]`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('contour-export-2017-12-14.csv', header=0, sep=',', usecols=[0,3,6,7], 
                 parse_dates = ['FCH_HORA_INICIO', 'FCH_HORA_TERMINO'], dayfirst = True)
```

Ambas columnas son parseadas teniendo en cuenta que el día va antes del mes en ambas columnas.